# Is it possible to set the default date format in JSON-B (Yasson) globally, instead of adding an annotation on every property?

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, payara, jsonb-api, yasson

I have using Jersey so far and I am doing my first implementation with JSON-B.

I am using Payara, so I working with Jersey and Yasson. I had an issue, because the serialized dates would always contain the "[UTC]" suffix.

I have managed to use an annotation on my date property, in my DTO. But I would like to configure that globally (in the JAX-RS application config?), instead of repeating myself on every date property. Is that possible? I haven't found anything so far...

Side question: I assume that it is possible to get rid of this "[UTC]" suffix, since it breaks all clients trying to parse the date. Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to this [Github issue](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jsonb-api/issues/75), I was able to solve my problem. Here is what I ended up writing in my code:

```
JSONConfigurator.java:

import javax.json.bind.Jsonb;
import javax.json.bind.JsonbBuilder;
import javax.json.bind.JsonbConfig;
import javax.json.bind.config.PropertyNamingStrategy;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class JSONConfigurator implements ContextResolver<Jsonb> {

  @Override
  public Jsonb getContext(Class<?> type) {
    JsonbConfig config = getJsonbConfig();
    return JsonbBuilder
      .newBuilder()
      .withConfig(config)
      .build();
  }

  private JsonbConfig getJsonbConfig() {
    return new JsonbConfig()
      .withDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", null);
  }
}
```

And:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@ApplicationPath("/api")    
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        addRestResourceClasses(resources);
        resources.add(JSONConfigurator.class);
        return resources;
    }


    private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
      ...
    }

}
```